# Read raw image as a string in C

Tags: c, embedded, odroid

I'm trying to show images on ODROID-SHOW screen. Using C code provided in the official examples by the official website, I managed to run c code and show simple texts. but when it comes to showing images, I'm stuck trying to read raw images and show them using the same code. Code is provided on the given link.

http://odroid.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=en:show_examples

I've a thoughts that if I could read raw image into a string I can simply send it to ODROID Screen. What do you think?

Comment: Please post the problematic code here, on this site.

Comment: Code doesn't even seem to be on that link.

Comment: Post image.sh code here

Comment: Assuming you are in fact trying to "[r]ead raw image as a string", that's not going to work - raw image data is not a C string.  A C-style string is a series of character values that are terminated with a NUL byte.  Raw image data is binary data that can include any value.

Comment: Perhaps you could somehow use XPM. This is a format of an image which is represented by a normal C string.

Comment: Attached is the shell script code:
https://github.com/hardkernel/ODROID-SHOW/blob/master/example/linux/images.sh

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by: `raw image`?   almost all images are packaged into a known format.  .tiff, .jpg, etc  Such packaged images have lots of control/etc information that should be properly processed to result in an image being displayed.  And what is the  `raw image` pixel format, 8 bit, 16bit, 24 bit, 32 bit? and are the pixels <rbg> or <yym> or what?

Comment: the linked files are in C++, java, bash, etc. so why is this question on a 'C' forum?

Comment: You might want to read <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536159/getting-rgb-values-for-each-pixel-from-a-raw-image-in-c> which discusses displaying *.raw images.

Comment: You might want to download/browse: <https://github.com/alexandruc/android-bpg> for an example of how to display a raw image on an android

Comment: this is from: <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format>   Providing a detailed and concise description of the content of raw files is highly problematic. There is no single raw format; formats can be similar or radically different. <snip>

Comment: Thanks guys, I got my problem solved.